Where can I study pure phenomenology?
Title. Five aggregates kind of thing, nature of conciousness, perception etc

Related: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13199/19249

Please see the following resources:

The Five Aggregates: A Study Guide by Ven. Thanissaro
Five Piles of Bricks: The Khandhas as Burden & Path by Ven. Thanissaro
The Self-made Private Prison by Lily de Silva
Cetasikas and Ruupa in The Abhidhamma in Practice by N.K.G. Mendis
The Discourse on the (Two Kinds of) Aggregates (SN 22.48), with commentary by Piya Tan
The Discourse on the Full Cycles of Clinging (SN 22.56), with commentary by Piya Tan
The Discourse on the All (SN 35.23), with commentary by Piya Tan
Five aggregates (panca kandha) YouTube playlist of Piya Tan


Thank you for the sources!

I think you really study it in the phenomena itself, right here, in your immediate experience, because that's what there is. It's where theory turns to practice, and potentially becomes direct knowledge. But yeah, first you have to learn how to investigate. I liked a Tibetan text called "The Wheel of Analytical Meditation" that teaches you how to examine the five heaps.
Some of the suttas have a systematic question and answer method to lead you into seeing how the aggregates are impermanent, subject to change, which causes suffering, which makes them unworthy of being clung to. The ones I know of that use that teaching method are SN 22.39, 22.83, 22.85, 22.100, MN 35, MN 109 and somewhat MN 106.
For the nature of five aggregates consciousness, you could search the suttas for the phrase "in dependence on a pair". An example would be how "eye consciousness" arises when the physical sense of sight makes contact with a visible object. "Contact" is one of the links in the chain of dependent arising. Another way of contemplating dependent co-arising is from Thich Nhat Hanh's "The Heart of the Buddha's Teaching" that someone posted:

To arrive at liberation from narrow views and to obtain fearlessness and great compassion, practice the contemplations on interdependence, impermanence, and compassion.
 
Sitting in meditation, direct your concentration onto the interdependent nature of certain objects. Remember that the subject of knowledge cannot exist independently from the object of knowledge. To see is to see something. To hear is to hear something. To be angry is to be angry about something. Hope is hope for something. Thinking is thinking about something. When the object of knowledge is not present, there can be no subject.
 
Meditate and see the interbeing of the subject and the object. When you practice mindfulness of breathing, then the breathing is mind. When you practice mindfulness of the body, then your body is mind. When you practice mindfulness of objects outside yourself, these objects are mind. Therefore, the contemplation of the interbeing of subject and object is also the contemplation of the mind. Every object of the mind is itself mind. In Buddhism, we call the objects of mind the dharmas.
 
Contemplation on interdependence is a deep looking into all dharmas in order to pierce through to their real nature, in order to see them as part of the great body of reality and in order to see that the great body of reality is indivisible. It cannot be cut into pieces with separate existences of their own.
 
The object of our mind can be a mountain, a rose, the full moon, or the person standing in front of us. We believe these things exist outside of us as separate entities, but these objects of our perceptions are us. This includes our feeling. When we hate someone, we also hate ourself. The object of our mindfulness is actually the whole cosmos. Mindfulness is mindfulness of the body, feelings, perceptions, any of the mental formations, and all of the seeds in our consciousness. The Four Establishments of Mindfulness contain everything in the cosmos. Everything in the cosmos is the object of our perception, and, as such, it does not exist only outside of us but also within us.
 
If we look deeply at the bud on the tree, we will see its nature. It may be very small, but it is also like the earth, because the leaf in the bud will become part of the earth. If we see the truth of one thing in the cosmos, we see the nature of the cosmos. Because of our mindfulness, our deep looking, the nature of the cosmos will reveal itself. It is not a matter of imposing our ideas on the nature of the cosmos.

If you think about it, everything that happens happens in the mind. Anything that doesn't happen in the mind is merely supposition as far as you know. "Beyond range", the Sabba Sutta says. It's like the story where Niels Bohr said to Einstein, prove the Moon exists when you're not looking at it. Or the tree falls in the wilderness and no one hears it koan.
Another way of investigating consciousness is to try to find the ultimate subject, the self, and they say when you eventually exhaust all hope of finding it, there's a chance of Realizing anatta. There's also the Zen practice of looking for the source of thought, where it arises from and where it ceases.

Thank you a lot for the helpful insights
